# Has any new physics problem been solved as a result of discussion on Physics StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Every now and then, there are very interesting science questions being posted on the Physics StackExchange. Some of these questions concern very up-to-date research. Does anyone know if any publication has resulted from a post on Physics StackExchange?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6299/2451

Comment: Does using an answer posted here in a dissertation count? Because I totally did that with one of my answers.

Comment: @KyleKanos Which one?

Comment: @HDE226868: [This one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108353/why-does-this-equation-refer-to-magnetic-tension/108358#108358); it wasn't verbatim copied, but the general idea was used. Though I want to point out that the concept of that answer wasn't an original thought, I had found it in the book I cited in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is just an assertion that none of the posted questions are genuinely new. Here's one that is: [What is the smallest possible electronic transistor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197941/what-is-the-smallest-possible-electronic-transistor) I do have in mind a 'radically different technique' for building it which has been posted (elsewhere) but the linked question is about the design/possibility of such a thing.

Answer (score -10):

This site actively discourages the kind of back-and-forth argumentation that is essential to the problem-sovling process (at least the way I solve problems). I solved some pretty good physics problem back when I used to go to physicsforums.com until the jackasses who oversee the site got me banned for life.

This [thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-does-decoherence-not-fully-solve-the-measurement-problem.385341/) illustrates the kind of horrifying argumentation that the guardians of this site are determined to avoid. But the reality is that I need the human element to get me stimulated. Without the hysterical insulting behavior of my correspondents at physicsforums.com, I probably woulnd't have been driven to come up with the explanation of how the light from a distant star can drive the transition on an ordinary photographic plate ([quantum siphoning](http://marty-green.blogspot.ca/2014/12/wave-function-collapse-explained-by.html)).

EDIT: This question has been up for a week and no one has posted a single example of a problem that's been solved thanks to a discussion on this site. I've posted an explanation of WHY no one is solving problems hear, and I've got eight downvotes so far.

Doesn't this tell you people anything? I'm cheating to get some discussion going here by posting this as an edit rather than a comment. But that's why nothing gets solved here...because there's no format for discussion. And don't tell me about the chat room...I'm not fourteen years old.

Comment: Er, so you've come up with some (as of yet, unpublished) theory based on discussions at Physics Forums, but how is that going to help Otto who wants to know about actual, published research here from Physics *Stack Exchange*.

Comment: Unlike most of the people who post here, I am not motivated by a desire to help Otto or those like him. I post here because it is an opportunity to promote my own ideas.

Comment: Note also that such "back and forth argumentation" is actually *quite welcome* on [Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), just not on the question pages (because this is a *Question and Answer* network, not a discussion site).

Comment: PhysicsForums was not run correctly, I was banned for life too. The points I made there were correct, PhysicsForums has indeed gone down the drain as I predicted it would all those years ago. Funny to see how they are now begging you to join if you visit that site. I can hardly resist to re-join just to poke them in the eyes :).

Comment: You'd be surprised at what 14-year-olds can do.

Comment: Marty, you are not alone. Probably I'm the most downvoted user around WITHOUT any argumentation,see my profile. You belong to a different kind of mind. You dare to have doubts and, at the same time, you are assertive -your site, your FxQI photon pea-shooter is a must, and the siphon viewpoint is fresh. Contrary to copy-pasters the physics can only advance thru opposition and theor physics is in the present a corps, a dead-end of medieval black-and dark-magic that people love. In the beginning this site was better. Marty, continue your work please. Keep going.

Comment: I'd say that downvoters- in meta this means people that don't agree with the answer- should at least give some argumentation on why they disagree, even if that's only based on an "this is not the site's policy" opinion- which is of-course respected.

Comment: I believe that this answers a different question, as you pointed out Marty. If you like, you could make your own question and answer that one. I believe the two reasons it is being downvoted is because it answers a different question, and the other (minor) reason is that the answer has fairly coarse language..

Comment: ^This guy (The poster of the answer)

Comment: I must have missed the "fourteen and under" sign on the chat...